# Why can't Internet Explorer run this simple jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm running a really simple jQuery script to grab all emails selected by checkboxes in a table. The table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="MD5HASH" />
            </td>
            <td>
                First Name
            </td>
            <td class="email">
                Email Address
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    var output = [];
    $("table tbody tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)").each(function() {
        var email = $('td.email', $(this)).text();
        if (validate(email) && output.indexOf(email) == -1)
            output.push(email);
    }); 

    $("#emails").val(output.join(", "));
});

function validate(email) {
    return /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/.test(email); 
}
```

This fails miserably in IE, but works everywhere else.

1. The `table tbody tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)` selector matches nothing.
2. The call to validate throws a `Object expected` error.

WHY!? Isn't jQuery designed to be cross-browser and portable?

Comment: Did you try to narrow down the problem by discovering whether or not the problem is with the regex?

Comment: try removing the tbody from the selector. IE often messes with tbody's I think

Comment: If `validate()` doesn't work, you might try wrapping the regex in parentheses - no sure whether IE can deal with `/regex/.test` syntax.

Comment: one of another important reason is that IE is simply a bad browser, microsoft should ship windows with Firefox, safari or google chrome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer (< 9) doesn't have [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).  Try using jQuery's [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead (it's cross browser and will actually use `Array.prototype.indexOf` if it exists :-P).

```
if (validate(email) && $.inArray(email,output) == -1)
  output.push(email);
```

Comment: RIDICULOUS. How can you _not_ support `indexOf`? I always just took it for granted in every other language that I use... you never know what you've got till it's gone.

Comment: @TKKocheran: You are aware you're using Internet Explorer, right?

Comment: I knew it was bad, but not _that_ bad!

Comment: @TKKocheran: At least IE 9 added it, finally.

Answer (score 1):

give the input a class and target it directly...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="emailchecked" type="checkbox" value="MD5HASH" />
            </td>
            <td>
                First Name
            </td>
            <td class="email">
                Email Address
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then target the checked ones in your js like this:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    var output = [];
    $(".emailchecked ([checked='checked'])").each(function() {
        var email = $('td.email', $(this)).text();
        if (validate(email) && output.indexOf(email) == -1)
            output.push(email);
    }); 

    $("#emails").val(output.join(", "));
});

function validate(email) {
    return /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/.test(email); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value=""/></td><td>one@gmail.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value=""/></td><td>two@gmail.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value=""/></td><td>three@gmail.com</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value=""/></td><td>four@gmail.com</td></tr>
     </table>

    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit"/>

    <div id="emails"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
        var emails = [];
        $('table').find('input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                emails.push($(this).parent().next().text());
        });

        $("#emails").empty().html(emails.join(", "));

    });
    </script>

Since you have three columns instead of two, just walk the DOM for that row.
```