# Is there a tool to determine if my jQuery will run cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, cross-browser

Recently, I discovered that Internet Explorer flat-out doesn't support certain selectors in jQuery (see [Why can't Internet Explorer run this simple jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812866/why-cant-internet-explorer-run-this-simple-jquery)). My question is: how can I know that my code will actually work while I'm writing it? Since I'm on Linux, my options are really just Chrome and Firefox. Is there a tool which emulates the functionality of major browsers for testing compatibility for a given site? My entire script mentioned in the above post failed for a few reasons but largely because the selector didn't get anything.

I initially thought that jQuery was cross-browser compliant, but it seems that selectors vary from browser to browser. Is there a way of testing for this?

Comment: Did you bother reading the answer to your question? jQuery provides a cross browser way of doing that. How is is jQuerys fault you are using an unsupported native method?

Comment: I don't understand why you think that selector doesn't work in IE.  The jQuery selector engine **is** quite consistent across browsers, including IE6.

Comment: jquery is cross-browser. It's javascript that isn't.  indexOf (for arrays) is a javascript function, jquery has nothing to do with it, and as an array function it wasn't implemented until ie9 or so.

Comment: Ok: does jQuery provide selectors that work cross-browser? One of the problems was that my selector in that question didn't work _specifically_ on IE.

Comment: Well, have you determined via a simple test case that it doesn't work?  I don't see anything suspicious about it.  (There's no "tool" as per what your question asks about, by the way.)

Comment: @TKKocheran: The answer you accepted to the previous question has *nothing* to do with selectors.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Understood, but nobody offered a selector that actually _does_ work. Instead, I simply modified my page layout to add a class to make it easier to select items. Plus, the `indexOf` problem was throwing errors and breaking everything.

Comment: FYI: a IE indexOf bug workaround: https://gist.github.com/1327877 anyway, it's IE's bug, not yours.

Comment: if the selector you're talking about is the input checkbox checked, I don't think you wrote it correctly, try `input:checked` instead of `input:checkbox:checked`

Comment: @Rodolfo selector: `table tbody tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)`

Comment: Look at this table: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a Linux user doesn't mean that you cannot use Internet Explorer. Create and start a Virtual Machine, such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), and simulate Windows + Internet Explorer.

Comment: You can't "simulate Windows" (well, not unless you use WINE, which doesn't give ideal results). You can run Windows in a VM (although you still have to buy a license).

Comment: He doesn't mention the fact that a windows license costs money which could be a deciding factor as well.

Comment: Windows images are available for free at the internet. Using common sense, it's not hard to get a real, safe image of Windows.

Comment: I think Microsoft runs the BizSpark program for these reasons - Small companies and entrepreneurs can very easily get access to Microsoft technologies for development.

Comment: Alright, well that works. I didn't know if Google or jQuery or someone like them had a library for testing these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf` function has nothing to do with jQuery. It's an array function. The selectors work just fine, it's just that the code you're using to process the results is not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: So why are you blaming jQuery?

Comment: I'm not blaming jQuery for that, my script failed mostly because the selector didn't grab anything, though it did grab stuff in Chrome/Chromium. The `indexOf` function is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, cross-browser testing is simply a PITA.  There's no real good way around it.  As was mentioned, setting up [virtual machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with various OS configurations is a good approach.  However, there are several "cloud" services online that allow you to "rent" boxes you can TS into and debug.  One such example I found with a quick Google search was: http://www.cloudtesting.com/

Though jQuery is a cross-platform library, it doesn't mean there doesn't exist bugs on certain browsers or certain versions of different browsers.  jQuery is an open-source project, and if you find bugs in their platform you're welcome to fix them or at least [report them](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket) so that they can be addressed.

For specific IE bugs, there are usually some work-arounds.  For example, if Array doesn't support indexOf, you can always implement it yourself by modifying the `Array.prototype`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) to get a screenshot in a LOT of browers.

Sometimes you have to wait a long time before you get the screenshot, and the code has to accessible to any computer. But it's not like you are publishing it to everyone.

I know that sometimes, a screenshot wont cut it. But it is better than nothing.